# How to unit test ML.NET prediction?

Tags: ml.net

I have a ML.NET project deployed as a web api like this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

How do I mock the PredictionEnginePool, MLContext or the PredictionEngine in xUnit or any unit test framework?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the tests for ML.NET?  MLContext is shown in those examples.
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/tree/master/test

PredictionEnginePool (I don't believe is shown), but it is not a special construct that can't be tested.  I would test the FileLoader and being able to test from remote locations if you have to.